# How to fix my draggable code in pure (vanilla) JavaScript, problem with moving div (div jumping or not moving)

Tags: javascript, html, draggable, dom-events, onmousemove

I try to write pure draggable element, moving element, I want to click on div move and put div somewhere on container.

https://codepen.io/kotbezbutow/pen/VJMbeK

I dont now how to fix my problem. If I calculate the differences between the cursor and the edge of div, my div not moving.

```
        moveDraggable() {
            document.onmousemove = (e) => {

                let elementX = this.element.offsetLeft;
                let elementY = this.element.offsetTop;

                let mouseDownX = e.clientX;
                let mouseDownY = e.clientY;



                if (this.draggable == undefined) {
                    return;
                }

                let roznica = (mouseDownX - elementX);

                this.draggable.style.left = mouseDownX + roznica + "px";
                this.draggable.style.top = mouseDownY - 40 +  "px";
            }
        }
```

All my works is on codepen https://codepen.io/kotbezbutow/pen/VJMbeK

Answer (score 1):

On mouse down, you need to store the delta between mouse position and div position.
Then, on mouse move, you have to subtract the previous delta to event mouse position

```
element.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    const rel = (() => {
        const x = event.clientX - parseInt(this.style.left)
        const y = event.clientY - parseInt(this.style.top)
        return { x: x, y: y }
    })()
    const moveHandler = event => {
        this.style.left = event.clientX - rel.x + 'px'
        this.style.top = event.clientY - rel.y + 'px'
    }
    const endHandler = () => {
        window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler, false)
        window.removeEventListener('mouseup', endHandler, false)
    }
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveHandler, false)
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', endHandler, false)
}
```

EDIT : for smooth move, you should use css translate instead of element left / top

Comment: Yes I now translate is better but in this project we need to do this on position left and top in the most the easiest way.

Comment: There is still a problem with your code: each time a mouse down event occured, you add 2 event listener (for mouse move and mouse up) which aren't used anymore once mouse up event is triggered. Follow my sample to remove those event once they're useless (I can't comment your answer so i post it here...)

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tried and succeeded, thx for help. The most important is calclulate differance between curosr and div position in mousedown not mousemove.

```
class Move {
    constructor(element) {

        this.border = undefined;
        this.draggable = undefined;

        document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {

            // get element and init draggable
            this.draggable = e.target.closest(element);

            let mouseDownX = e.clientX;
            let mouseDownY = e.clientY;

            let elementX = this.draggable.offsetLeft;
            let elementY = this.draggable.offsetTop;

            this.differanceX = mouseDownX - elementX;
            this.differanceY = mouseDownY - elementY;

            // move draggable
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {

                // return if end
                if (this.draggable == undefined) {
                    return;
                }

                let mouseDownX = e.clientX;
                let mouseDownY = e.clientY;

                this.draggable.style.left = mouseDownX - this.differanceX + "px";
                this.draggable.style.top = mouseDownY - this.differanceY + "px";

            });

            document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
                this.draggable = undefined;
            });

        });
    }
}
```